# How to notify user that someone is writing in the same room?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to notify a user that someone is writing in the same room. When I'm emitting that someone writes it's working properly. The problem begins when I'm trying to notify only users in the same room. Nothing happens. Thanks in advance.

I was wondering if I made any mistake in joining/leaving rooms, but I think it's not a problem because I can send messages in these rooms.

`server`

```
var express = require("express");
var socket = require("socket.io");

var app = express();
var PORT = 5000;
server = app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

var rooms = ["general", "room1", "room2"];
var usernames = {};

io = socket(server);

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log(`connected user with id: ${socket.id}`);

  socket.on("adduser", username => {
    console.log(username);
    socket.username = username;
    console.log(`socket username = ${socket.username}`);
    socket.room = "general";
    console.log(`socket room: ${socket.room}`);
    usernames[username] = username;
    socket.join("general");
    socket.emit("updatechat", "SERVER", "you have connected to general room.");
    socket.broadcast
      .to("general")
      .emit("updatechat", "SERVER", username + " has connected to this room.");
    socket.emit("updaterooms", rooms, "general");
  });

  socket.on("switchRoom", (previousRoom, newroom) => {
    socket.leave(previousRoom);
    socket.join(newroom);
    console.log(socket.rooms);
    socket.emit(
      "updatechat",
      "SERVER",
      socket.username + " has left this room."
    );
    socket.broadcast
      .to(newroom)
      .emit("updatechat", "SERVER", socket.username + " has joined this room.");
    socket.emit("updaterooms", rooms, newroom);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(`disonnected user with id: ${socket.id}`);
    delete usernames[socket.username];
    io.sockets.emit("updateusers", usernames);
    socket.broadcast.emit(
      "updatechat",
      "SERVER",
      socket.username + " has disconnected."
    );
    socket.leave(socket.room);
  });

  socket.on("typing", currentRoom => {
    socket.broadcast.to(currentRoom).emit("typing");
    console.log("pisze");
  });

  socket.on("nottyping", user => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("nottyping", user);
    console.log("nie pisze");
  });

  socket.on("SEND_MESSAGE", function(data) {
    io.emit("RECEIVE_MESSAGE", data);
  });
});
```

`client side`

```
import React from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

const socket = socketIOClient("http://localhost:5000");

class MessageInput extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  componentDidMount = props => {
    socket.on("typing", () => {
      console.log(`received typing`);
      this.props.handleUpdateTyping(true);
    });

    socket.on("nottyping", () => {
      console.log(`received not typing`);
      this.props.handleUpdateNotTyping(false);
    });

    socket.on("RECEIVE_MESSAGE", username => {
      console.log(`received message`);
      console.log(username);
      this.props.handleUpdateAddMessage(username);
    });
  };

  timeoutFunction = () => {
    console.log("in timeout");
    this.props.handleUpdateIsTyping(false);
    socket.emit("nottyping");
  };

  onKeyDownNotEnter = () => {
    if (this.props.isTyping === false) {
      this.props.handleUpdateIsTyping(true);
      var timeout = setTimeout(this.timeoutFunction, 1200);
      console.log(timeout);
      this.props.handleUpdateTimeout(timeout);
    } else {
      socket.emit("typing", this.props.currentRoom);
      console.log("timeout to clear", this.props.timeoutValue);
      clearTimeout(this.props.timeoutValue);
      this.props.handleUpdateTimeout(setTimeout(this.timeoutFunction, 1200));
    }
  };

  handleEnterSend = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      this.sendMessage(e);
    }
  };

  sendMessage = e => {
    socket.on("updatechat", function(username, data) {
      // $('#conversation').append('<b>'+username + ':</b> ' + data + '<br>');
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit(
      "SEND_MESSAGE",
      {
        author: this.props.username,
        message: this.props.message,
        currentRoom: this.props.currentRoom
      },
      this.state.currentRoom
    );
    this.props.clearMessage();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        value={this.props.value}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type your message here"
        onChange={event => {
          console.log(event.target.value);
          this.props.handleUpdateInputChanges(event.target.value);
          this.onKeyDownNotEnter();
        }}
        onKeyUp={this.handleEnterSend}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default MessageInput;
```

I expect that the user should be notified only when someone is writing in room. When I'm using `socket.broadcast.emit("typing")` instead of `socket.broadcast.to(currentRoom).emit("typing")` everything works fine, but writing notification is emitting to all rooms.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by passing to socket event the current room from server and checking it on client side if the room compares with client room.

`server side`

```
socket.on("typing", data => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("typing", data.currentRoom);
}
```

`client side`

```
socket.on("typing", serverRoom => {
      if (this.props.currentRoom === serverRoom) {
        this.props.handleUpdateTyping(true);
      }
    });
```